# How can I create a certificate for my new domain?

Tags: server, apache2, raspberrypi, certificates

I'm trying to change my domain in my raspberry as it was configured for an old domain with an old certificate

The problem is that when I try to run the installer or make anything I only find this error:

```
Error while running apache2ctl configtest.
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

AH00526: Syntax error on line 33 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/lastchancerp.com/fullchain.pem' does not exist or is empty
```

I did `sudo certbot delete` which could be the cause...

Old domain is **lastchacerp.com** as you can see in the error path

How can I create a certificate for my new domain?

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: You will need to first remove the SSL certificate line from the Apache configuration and run through the Let'sEncrypt steps for the new site. Then you can attach the new certificate to your Apache configuration and restart the web server.